# How to clean the vagina of a newborn?

Tags: newborn, health, hygiene

She is 9 day old.
I am seeing some whitish sticky substance *surrounding* her clitoris for past some days.
Do I need to clean it? If yes, how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is probably just [vernix](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2528704/):

> Vernix is a greasy white substance that coats and protects baby’s skin
>   in the mother’s uterus. Some babies are born with lots of vernix still
>   on their skin. It is harmless and can be washed or wiped off. Losing
>   vernix may cause the skin to peel during the first week of life. This
>   is normal and will go away on its own.

You can wash with baby wipes, just warm water, or warm water with a very mild soap.

In your question you referred to her vagina, which is internal and should not be cleaned. You should only clean external organs.

Source: National Institute of Health: *Paediatrics & Child Health*

Answer (score 0):

I was told to leave it alone. you don't want to irritate her vagina, it should come out with a good bath in warm water & gentle soap.